# How can Present perfect describe my current status?

Tags: present-perfect

I've read before that present perfect describes my current status. Could anyone please explain this concept?

For example when i say "I've written something" how can this describe my status?

Comment: The pr.pf **may** describe your current status; it is not obliged to do so.

Comment: Could you please explain in which cases it describe current status? Or any examples.

Comment: @Mmm I think the current relevance is understood by the listener; it's not explicitly stated. So without a sufficient context, I think it's really hard to explain. We have a [cannonical post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it) covering this topic. I hope you read it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I, too, recommend the [Canonical Post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32) which user178049 links—I wrote it, so I pretty much have to!—but it's very long, so you might find a summary version of the relevant parts valuable.

- [3.1 grammatical meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13260/32) – A present perfect does not speak about the past event it mentions: it speaks about a **present** state which in some arises out of the past event. BUT:
- [3.2 pragmatic meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/32) – A present perfect does not itself name the present state it is speaking about: that is left to be 'filled in' by the speaker, or (more often) **inferred** by the hearer from the discourse context.

Take (for example) your sentence "I've written something": this may have a variety of meanings, depending on the context:

> **A:** I'd like to know more about the uses of the present perfect.
>   **B:** In fact I've written something.  *This is a* resultative perfect: *A infers that as a result of B's writing a document exists which will inform him about the present perfect—more or less adequately, depending on A's knowledge of B's expertise in the matter.*
>
> **A:** Do you know anything about the present perfect?
>   **B:** Yes, I've written something. *This is an* experiential *or* existential perfect: *A infers from the existence of this writing in B's experience that B is sufficiently knowledgeable about the present perfect, and sufficiently interested in the subject, to put his thoughts into writing. This is probably what your source means by 'current status'.*

There's also a *continuative perfect*, which names a prior state which the hearer infers still obtains in the present; but this can't ordinarily be expressed by a dynamic (that is, non-stative) verb designating a single event, like *write something*. I could however say

> I've written on the uses of the present perfect since 2013, *from which you might infer that my state of activity has persisted into the present—I'm still writing about uses of the present perfect. As indeed I am.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I jaut want to ask the " recent past " considered under which type of the three types in your answer ? Or it's just a special case ?

Comment: @Mmm This is the "hot news" category McCawley advanced in 1971 but later withdrew as superfluous, because instances may be understood from context as either experiential or resultative.